# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS(sql server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(column_1) 
FROM  table_name1 
WHERE CREATEDATE BETWEEN  (SELECT MONTH(07), YEAR(2017)FROM table_name1) 
                 AND (SELECT MONTH(11), YEAR(2017)FROM table_name1).
```

my query is as follows, but im getting error as

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I need to compare between from @fromdate(month and year) to @todate(month and year)

Comment: `CREATEDATE` contains a *single* value (per row). Each of your subselects are returning *two* values. How do you expect this to work? What data type is `CREATEDATE`?

Answer (score 0):

Your sub queries in `WHERE` are returning two values which is causing the error "Only one expression can be specified in the select".

You can use SQL `DATEFROMPARTS` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to convert all three dates (CreateDate, @fromdate & @todate) to first day of that month-year and use them in `WHERE` clause using `BETWEEN` like below.

```
SELECT COUNT(column_1) 
FROM  table_name1 
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(CreateDate),MONTH(CreateDate),1) 
      BETWEEN  DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(@fromdate),MONTH(@fromdate),1) 
      AND DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(@Todate),MONTH(@ToDate),1)
```